# Mount Azure storage in Docker Swarm

Tags: azure, docker, containers, docker-swarm, samba

I have successfully set-up a docker swarm on an Azure scale-set, all good. Now, i need to mount an Azure storage device on my container to utilize my app, this is ofc. simple with "docker run" since i can add capabilities; but this cannot be achieved through "docker service create". What are the possibilities for me to mount storage shares (CIFS/Samba) on the autoscaling nodes for my container?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a volume plugin for Docker to mount Azure storage entities as a volume using a volume driver: https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver

[image: Example from https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As you may notice this is more than a year old (last update) and it is not working for swarm services but utilizes (Docker run). Thanks.